# How to pass values from a html page to a simple java class

Tags: web-services

I am new to Web services and UIs. I have been asked to create a restful web service for create modify and update user. I also should have a front end for my application. For passing the values from the front end page(in html) to the web service I was asked to use Ajax. There are many tutorials for the same but I could not find one that matches my application.

Please tell me how should I proceed. Thanks in advance
(Also I am not to use servlets)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JQuery, it helps a lot with simplifying Ajax calls.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

To send data to the back end, you should make a POST request.

```
$.post("YourTargetUrl",
    {
        value1: "something",
        value2: "something else"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
);
```

On the back end, how to retreive these values depends on what tech you are using.